# recursive function in R

Tags: r, recursion

I want to understand this problem. I stop understanding after the `for` statement.

This is a recursive program (prints all the possible ways that an amount x (in cents) can be made up using Australian coins (5, 10, 20, 50, 100, and 200 cent denominations)). Each decomposition is ordered.

```
change <- function(x, y.vec = c()) {
    # finds possible ways of making up amount x using Australian coins 
    # x is given in cents and we assume it is divisible by 5
    # y.vec are coins already used (so total amount is x + sum(y.vec)) 

    if (x == 0) {
        cat(y.vec, "\n")
    } else {
        coins <- c(200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5) 
        new.x <- x - coins
        new.x <- new.x[new.x >= 0]
        for (z in new.x) {
            y.tmp <- c(y.vec, x - z)
            if (identical(y.tmp, sort(y.tmp))) {
                change(z, y.tmp)
            }
        }
    }
    return(invisible(NULL))
}
```

Rewrite this program so that instead of writing its output to the screen it returns it as a list, where each element is a vector giving a possible decomposition of x.

Answer (score 0):

Since the algorithm considers every coin every time through the loop, it would be possible to come up with multiple results for the same set of coins, (for example  35 = 5+10+20 = 5+20+10 = 10+20+5 are the same answer three different ways). The logic inside the loop ensures the answer is only given once, sorted by low to high value coins, since `if (identical(y.tmp, sort(y.tmp)))` evaluates to `TRUE` only once, the first time it is encountered.  (Replace the logic inside the loop with `change(z, c(y.vec, x - z))` in order to see the difference).

Comment: Looking at the date when the question was asked, I am afraid her homework was already due. ;)